# Conversion from Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records to Kaminari::PaginatableArray

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

This is what I have:

```
@parts = if params[:q].present?
           Part.search(params[:q]).records
         else
           Part.find_by_params(params)
         end
```

if condition returns true @parts == Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records otherwise @parts == Kaminari::PaginatableArray

Some methods I'm using with @parts doesn't work (with Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records) if condition is true.

Is there any way I can convert Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records to Kaminari::PaginatableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@parts = if params[:q].present?
           Kaminari.paginate_array(
            Part.search(params[:q]).records.to_a
           ).page[params[:page])
            .per(10)
         else
           Kaminari.paginate_array(
            Part.find_by_params(params)
           ).page(params[:page])
            .per(10)
         end
```

It's generally not a good idea to have a method return two different types of things like that - it introduces exactly this sort of problem.  But if you *do* need two different quack-alikes - it's often helpful to introduce an adapter class to manage subtle differences in the interface.

Also - Elasticsearch does it's own pagination - so you you probably want to pass those pagination parameters into the search query.

Comment: I know this is not a good idea but I do need to implement something like this.Anyway thanks for advice.